# My discord bot not updating status when it joins a new server

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

My bot not updating when someone invites my bot to their/another server.
I have to restart the code, then it is working. I want that my bot updated when someone invites in status.

My current code is:

PREFIX = <

```js
client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`${client.user.username} ready!`);
  client.user.setActivity(`${PREFIX}help | ${PREFIX}play  ${client.guilds.cache.size} servers `, { type: "LISTENING" });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to update the bot's status whenever your bot joins a new server. Instead of using an unnecessary `setInterval` to check the cached guild size every X seconds, you could use the [`guildCreate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildCreate) event.

It emits whenever the client joins a guild, so whenever it fires, you can update the activity inside its callback:

```js
// emitted when the client becomes ready to start working
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`${client.user.username} is ready!`);

  client.user.setActivity(
    `${PREFIX}help | ${PREFIX}play | ${client.guilds.cache.size} servers`,
    { type: 'LISTENING' },
  );
});

// emitted whenever the client joins a guild
client.on('guildCreate', (guild) => {
  console.log(`${client.user.username} joined the ${guild.name} server`);

  client.user.setActivity(
    `${PREFIX}help | ${PREFIX}play | ${client.guilds.cache.size} servers`,
    { type: 'LISTENING' },
  );
});
```

PS: your client needs the `GUILDS` intent to be enabled

Answer (score 1):

You must update your status every X seconds. Your code that you are using right now just updated when the bot is ready.

To do this you must set a Interval to run the code every X seconds.

```
client.on("ready", () => {

    console.log(`${client.user.username} ready!`);

    setInterval(() => {
        client.user.setActivity(`${PREFIX}help | ${PREFIX}play  ${client.guilds.cache.size} servers `, { type: "LISTENING" });
    }, 15000);

})
```

The `15000` is the ms (milisecond) that you want your bot to update the status. (1000ms is equal to 1 Second.)

Due to the [Discord API rules](https://discord.com/developers/docs/rich-presence/how-to#updating-presence), to prevent spam, you can only update your bot status **minimal** every 15 seconds